# Proving that $L\{e^{at}\} = \frac{1}{s-a} s>a$

Tags: laplace-transform

**The question states:**
if $f(t)=e^{at}$ find $L\{f(t)\}$.

**Solution**
$$\begin{align}
L\{e^{at}\} &= \int^\infty_0e^{-st}\cdot e^{at}\\
&=\lim_{B\rightarrow\infty}\int^B_0e^{-t(s-a)}dt\\
&=\lim_{B\rightarrow\infty}\left[\frac{e^{-t(s-a)}}{-(s-a)}\right]^B_0\\
&=\lim_{B\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{e^{-B(s-a)}-1}{-(s-a)}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{s-a}  &s>0
\end{align}$$

**My questions are:**
- How do we go from line 2 to line 3?
 Where does the "$-(s-a)$" come from in the denominator in line 3? This must be some kind of lookup, no?
- And then, line 3 to line 4?
 I see that we are substituting t for B but where does the "$-1$" come from in the numerator in line 4?

Comment: That's the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. What you have in line 3 is an antiderivative of the integrand of line 2. Just differentiate to check, with the chain rule.

Comment: According to http://bit.ly/111XHei line 2 should simply become $e^{-B(s-a)}$. I still don't get where the denominator comes from or the "-1" in the numerator in line 4?

Comment: The derivative of $e^{-t(s-a)}$ is $-(s-a)e^{-(s-a)t}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

What is the $\int e^{-w t} dt$?

Now, substitute $w = s-a$.

What is $e^{0}$ and the negative sign comes from the FTC using the lower limit of integration.

Is it clear now?